# How to get a gmail message reading datetime

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

Is there a way to get a message reading datetime through GMail API, other than by observing the change of unread label presence in a message?

By observing I mean periodically syncing messages with [Users.history](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history) resource or using [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is not changed in any way except for the `UNREAD`-label being removed when it is read, so you will have to observe the change like you mentioned.